# Intellij - create custom setter for immutable objects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, immutability, setter

I'm trying to write a setter template in Intellij that will generate conventional immutable setters, those that create and return a new object instance upon setting a member.
e.g.

```
Person setName(String name) {
  return new Person(age, name);
}
```

Has anyone been here before?

Answer (score 3):

A non answer: don't call this a setter.

By convention, a setter changes the instance you call it on.

So rather call it *createCloneWithName()* or something alike.

I guess you might be able to provide special templates to IntelliJ for such clone methods. But don't try to misuse setter generation for your purpose.

Comment: For a good name: I like the `copy` method in Kotlin (language by the company that makes IntelliJ) data classes, and they have optional parameters, eg `person.copy(name= "New Name)`, copies all the properties, and provides a new one for name.

Answer (score 0):

Under setting->Editor->Live Templates, you can use live templates with a template something like:

```
$TYPE$ set$NAME$($IN_TYPE$ $PARAM$) {
    return new $TYPE$($PARAM$);
}
```

Where PARAM is defined with the expression "camelCase(NAME)"
and TYPE is defined with the expression "className()"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieved it (with credit to [this post](https://coderedirect.com/questions/573437/can-intellij-generate-getters-without-the-get-prefix)):

1. Alt+Insert
2. Select Setter
3. Open the template configuration from '...' on the RHS
4. Create a new template from the LHS - see example below
5. Ok and select your new template

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static void ##
#else
  $classSignature ##
#end
set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
  this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
#if(!$field.modifierStatic)
return this;
#end
}
```